# Typescript: Send method signature with params as another method argument?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I have a React app in which the actions are in a separate file from the service methods

hoplite.actions.ts

```
export const fetchBattleResult = createAsyncThunk<Result>(
'battle/fetchBattleResult',
HopliteService.battleResult,
);
```

hoplite.service.ts

```
const battleResult = async (item: Battle): Promise<Result> =>
  await fetch(`${API_URL}/battle`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(item),
  }).then((response) => response.json());
```

As the service method receives parameter, VSCode is giving me this error in when sending the signature of battleResult.

```
Argument of type '(item: Battle) => Promise<Result>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<Result, void, {}>'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'arg' are incompatible.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Battle'.ts(2345)
```

Is there another way to send the signature so it includes the params? Or maybe at least specify them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because you specify the first generic argument, the second one automatically goes to the fallback value, which is `void`. You either need to specify all arguments - or none, and allow for inference. TypeScript cannot mix explicit and inferred type arguments.

Either of those would be correct.

```
export const fetchBattleResult = createAsyncThunk(
  "battle/fetchBattleResult",
  HopliteService.battleResult
);
```

or

```
export const fetchBattleResult = createAsyncThunk<Result, Battle>(
  "battle/fetchBattleResult",
  HopliteService.battleResult
);
```